# modelling and if/else pattern inside an rxjs observable pipeline

Tags: javascript, if-statement, rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

I have an epic where I am listening to an action stream, when an action of `'AUTH_STATUS_CHECKED'` occurs switch over to a new observable `authState(app.auth())`. This new observable tells me if I am authenticated or not.

If the auth observable returns a user then dispatch `'SIGNED_IN'` action with the user as the payload.

If a user does not exist then fore off a promise `app.auth().signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)` and when you get the response dispatch `'SIGNED_IN'`.

If there are any errors, catch them and let me know in the console.

based on the logic above I have implemented the pipeline below

```
export const fetchAuthStatus = action$ =>
      action$.pipe(
        ofType('AUTH_STATUS_CHECKED'),
        switchMap(() =>
          authState(app.auth()).pipe(
            map(user =>
              user
                ? { type: 'SIGNED_IN', payload: user }
                : app
                    .auth()
                    .signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)
                    .then(user => ({ type: 'SIGNED_IN', payload: user }))
            ),
            catchError(error => console.log('problems signing in'))
          )
        )
      );
```

It's not working as expected. If there is no user the promise gets fired but it does not wait for the response and the dispatch never gets fired.

I'm clearly new to rxjs and I'm having trouble figuring this out. I've gone through the docs and tried using a tap() and mergeMap() but am getting the same error.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to wait until some inner Observable/Promise completes you need to wrap it with eg. `mergeMap` or `concatMap`. Since both of these operators require that you return an Observable/Promise you'll have to wrap the action with `of()` to turn a plain object into an Observable:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...
mergeMap(user => user
  ? of({ type: 'SIGNED_IN', payload: user })
  : app.auth().signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

However your code can be optimized a bit and recommend do it in a better way, what you are missing here, is that `map` expect a plain object, while `switchMap` expect a `Promise` or `Observable` object.

```
const signIn = (authProvider) => app.auth().signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)
    .then(user => ({ type: 'SIGNED_IN', payload: user }));

export const fetchAuthStatus = action$ =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType('AUTH_STATUS_CHECKED'),
        switchMap(() => authState(app.auth())),
        switchMap(user => user // <-- switchMap handle Promises or Observables
            ? of({ type: 'SIGNED_IN', payload: user }) // <-- returning an observable
            : signIn(googleAuthProvider) // <-- returning a promise
        ),
        catchError(error => console.log('problems signing in'))
    );
```

#### Notes:

- Don't nest pipe operator, try to use one pipe as much as possible
- Extract complicated method outside the Rx stream
- use the `of` operator to convert plain object to Observable

Comment: I marked the other answer correct since that was answered correctly first. But thank you very much for taking the time to explain why, this is very helpful and I appreciate it.